# Modern graphics card requirements

Tags: graphics-card, compatibility

I have about 5 years old motherboard GA-MA790FXT-UD5P, and I'm thinking of upgrading graphics card. I would like to know that are there any reasons that any modern graphics card wouldn't be compatible with my motherboard? My PSU Seasonic  S12II-500 500W ATX 2.2.

Comment: Your motherboard has two PCI Express 2.0 x16 slots.  This means any graphic card that requiress less then say a 400W power supply can be installed in your system.  But this sort of question isn't really on topic here at Superuser.  I suggest something a website with a discussion forum dedecated to computer hardware for this type of question.

Comment: Ok, I just searched and saw similar questions, so I assumed it's ok to ask. And obviously you know something about this issue, so where is the harm? Do you know any similar place where I could ask questions like this?

Comment: Your current question asks if they is any reason that any graphics card wouldn't be compatible. I can list tons of cards that would not be compatible with your current hardware. What exactly is your question? A PCI-E 2.0 graphics card will be supported by your hardware. PCI-E 3.0 is backwards compatible. This question seems better suited for a discussion board since it really requires a discussion about your exact hardware.

Comment: Not really related to exact hardware, more like PCI 2.0 hardware. So now I now that I could use some PCI-E 3.0 cards, because those are backwards compatible, make sure that card doesn't require power connectors and that it requires less than 400W power supply. So somebody else could also need this information.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like your motherboard [supports](http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=3005#ov) PCI 2.0. Most modern video cards are PCI 3.0 and PCI 3.0 video cards are backwards compatible with PCI 2.0 motherboards.

Comment: Yes, but make sure that your PSU can provide enough current and that the graphics card doesn't require two 8-pin power connectors.